# Using cloudflare api to delete a file from cache not working

Tags: php, curl, cloudflare

Here is my code for trying to delete a file a file via the api

```
$ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/<MY-ZONE-ID>/purge_cache");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $headers = [
            'X-Auth-Email:  MYEMAIL',
            'X-Auth-Key: MY-AUTH-KEY',
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        ];

        $data = json_encode(array("files" => "https://example.com/file/".$filename));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
```

The response i get is as follows

```
{
   "success":false,
   "errors":[
      {
         "code":1012,
         "message":"Request must contain one of \"purge_everything\" or \"files\", or \"tags"
      }
   ],
   "messages":[

   ],
   "result":null
}
```

Documentation says tag is optional so it should work

```
curl -X DELETE "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/023e105f4ecef8ad9ca31a8372d0c353/purge_cache" \
     -H "X-Auth-Email: user@example.com" \
     -H "X-Auth-Key: c2547eb745079dac9320b638f5e225cf483cc5cfdda41" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     --data '{"files":["http://www.example.com/css/styles.css"],"tags":["some-tag","another-tag"]}'
```

What am In doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I maybe because your `files` property is not an array.

Try

```
$data = json_encode(array("files" => array("https://example.com/file/".$filename)));
```

Comment: Can you remove the `http_build_query` and test again?

Comment: removal of `http_build_query` and `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);` fixed it

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit confusing.  Post Data is usually sent in key value pairs.
Also when the post data is an array curl changes the content type to `multipart/form-data`

When post data is sent as a query string, it's in the format of `key1=value1&key2=value2`

It appears the json is the value with no key.

I would try it both as an array and string and look at the request header.
In the request header look at the content-type and the data.

To get the request header in the curl return add this option: 
`curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);`

You may need to add:
 
`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);`

```
$data[] = json_encode(array('files'=>"https://example.com/file/$filename"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);

$data = json_encode(array('files'=>"https://example.com/file/$filename"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);
```

PS: You do not need to use the . concatenation when using double quotes for `$filename`